# ubuntu touch clarification, presence of full desktop on tablet, and hardware recommendation

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

First time I post here, but I am a long time reader of the forum.

I recently stumbled upon the BQ M10 tablet, ubuntu edition, only to find out that it is sold out.

https://www.bq.com/en/aquaris-m10-ubuntu-edition

So I was considering getting the android version and flashing the device myself. Or better yet, get another compatible device with more RAM and use that (recommendations for hardware are very welcome).

I just need a few clarifications as google wasn't a great help.

As I understand it, there is no difference between ubuntu touch and ubuntu for phones. But there is a difference between ubuntu desktop and ubuntu touch (the latter running MIR with unity 8, which is used on phones).

Given that touch an desktop editions are different; if I flash the current build of ubuntu touch on a device, will that automatically include desktop mode if I connect peripherals (similar to what is advertised on the BQ website)? It should be the case, but would like to make sure. To specify: I am not so keen to have the desktop on an external display, but rather on the tablet itself.

Another question would be; will flashing the BQ tablet basically give me the ubuntu edition they are selling or are there differences to what OEMs can do as opposed to us.

Cheers and many thanks in advance.

A

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. I answered your first (main) question. Please open a new question for your second question about the OEMs and then remove this second question from this thread.:)

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding there is no other working tablet as of yet, at least it is not promoted, but you can go and have a look for yourself https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

you are right about your assumptions regarding touch and desktop, yet the touch images for `frieza` and `cooler` are prepared for the convergence experience so with periphals attached it will behave like a desktop. There are also options to run it in `windowed-mode` without attached screen. (sorry can't find the link quickly)

**Be aware that all `ubuntu-touch`-images are as for now targeted towards developers** - this means it might not work flawlessly and can be more of an hurdle than an help in production use. This said if you want to go along with this, I recommend reading the lengthy install instructions here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right.

Ubuntu Desktop is not the same as Ubuntu Touch, which is sometimes called Ubuntu for Phones.

The Names are sometimes confusing, but I try my very best to explain what I have unserstood sofar.:
Ubuntu Touch includes Mir and Unity 8 and it includes the possibility to switch into the convergenced mode to enjoy a full desktop with multiplewindows, whichis one of the Ubuntu Touch 's core features. This desktop mode looks NOT the same as the Ubuntu Desktop version, because Ubuntu Desktop uses x11 and Unity 7. In future I guess there will be only one version winch combines the Ubuntu Touch and the the Ubuntu Desktop Version.

But remember, right now Ubuntu Touch cannot run all x11 apps. So Ubuntu Touch 's desktop mode is more like a reduced Version of Ubuntu Desktop.